# Why the positive lookahead not working with /$ in the end

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

So I want to match `issues/` or `settings/general/` but in the second case `/general` should not be included in the match, so i tried using positive lookahead for the second case but it does not seems to be working, this is what i came up with.

```
^(issues|settings(?=/general))/$
```

Comment: You require `general` to appear after the final `/` with the lookahead (which can't happen since end of string is expected after `/`). With `re`, you can only do that with two groups, `^(?:(issues)|(settings)/general)/$`

Comment: Well, try `^(issues(?=/$)|settings(?=/general/$))`, which looks a bit redundant, but does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `/general` part of the string is not consumed.

After having checked that `settings` is correctly followed by `/general`, the cursor is still at the end of `settings`, so the matching will continue from this point on.
So the slash is correctly matched, but not the end of line.

As suggested by Wiktor, you'd be better off using groups if you want to extract a part of the string.
Here's a proposition:

```
^(issues|settings)/general/$
```

Trying it out:

```
>>> result = re.match("^(issues|settings)/general/$", "issues/general/")
>>> result
<re.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='issues/general/'>
>>> result.group(1)
'issues'
```

If you really want to avoid groups though, you can also include `/$` inside the lookahead, and so the regex becomes `^(issues|settings(?=/general/$))`:

```
>>> re.match("^(issues|settings(?=/general/$))", "issues/general/")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='issues'>
```

Comment: thanks for the explaination but can you also help with the solution?

Comment: @MOntu sure thing, I just edited my answer.